# Using polar coordinates evaluate the integral

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Can you help me to solve these questions? I'm totally lost here.

a) $\iint_D e^{-(x^2+y^2)}~dx~dy, D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 2\}$

b) $\iint_D \frac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}~dx~dy, D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\geq 9, x^2+y^2\leq 25\}$

Comment: it would be better if you type them

Comment: $\iint\limits_{D} e^{-(x^2+y^2)}~\text{d}x\text{d}y = \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}e^{-r^2}r~\text{d}r\text{d}\theta$  Can you see how that was performed?  Do you know how to continue?

Comment: May I ask exactly where you are stuck with these problems? For instance, are you stuck with the substitution, or are you stuck with finding the limits for the integrals for $r$ and $\theta$?

Comment: First thing is I'm newbie so I don't know how to write mathematical equations. And I'm totally bad at math and I search internet and I'm stuck at with finding the limits for integrals for  r and θ. Thank you for who is REALLY helping me to understand.

Comment: @CannurKartum Try to sketch the region of integration $D$ for each case in the $x$-$y$ plane. What type of geometrical shapes do you get?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For $a,b\ge 0$
$$
\int_{a^2<x^2+y^2<b^2} f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{a<r<b} rf(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)drd\theta
$$

Comment: Even better, both problems here will succumb to$$\int_{a^2\le x^2+y^2\le b^2}g^\prime(x^2+y^2)dxdy=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_a^brg^\prime(r^2)dr=\pi(g(b^2)-g(a^2))$$for $0\le a<b$.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to polar coordinates, you have $r^2=x^2+y^2$. So for your first integral, the region $D$ consists of those points where $r^2\leq 2$; that is, $r\leq\sqrt2$. Then
$$
\iint_D e^{-(x^2+y^2)}~dx~dy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt2}e^{-r^2}\,r\,dr\,d\theta=2\pi\,\int_0^{\sqrt2}e^{-r^2}\,r\,dr=\pi(1-e^{-2})
$$
For your second integral you now have $9\leq r^2\leq 25$, so your integral becomes 
$$
\iint_D \frac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}~dx~dy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_3^5\frac{r}{r^2-1}\,dr\,d\theta.
$$